# Any way to make touch-control work with ScrollControls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, 3d, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm really very bad at programming and to be honest I'm a designer.

However, I need to fix the problem so that scrolling works on touch devices as well.

https://codesandbox.io/s/diamond-rflx8p?file=/src/App.js

I tried to add touchmove, touchstart etc listeners.

Set

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        touch-action: touch !important;
```

to #root and canvas. There is no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is very simple. I guess OrbitControls conflict with ScrollControls. Disabling one of these will enable either.